# How to get an original One Dark Theme fonts?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-code

I've been playing with the font settings in my VS Code and changed accidentally the font, this is how my 'font' setting looks right now:

[image: Settings]

I want to set the One Dark Pro theme: [theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zhuangtongfa.Material-theme)

But after choosing it, I received the weird font: 
[image: font]

How I can set the font from One Dark Pro theme?

Comment: also, the space between tabs is super-small(

Comment: The font from the theme Market Place page looks a lot like `Source Code Pro`

Answer (score 1):

It is [Source Code Pro](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro/releases),
so just download the Font and in the settings, set the Font Family to `Source Code Pro`

Your font setting looks broken, remove all content of the Settings field and just put `Source Code Pro` in there without any quotation marks.